# Get every 100th record starting from the top

Tags: mysql, sql, join, xampp

I have a table earnings with 4436 records with two columns - `no_id` (which is unique) and `payments`.
I want to extract a query which will give a row of start & end column with a gap of 100. the gap of hundred can be varied depending upon user input and can be anything between 1-250.

Original Table

```
no_id, payments 

4436, 7540

4435, 7900

4434, 8000

4433, 4500
'
'
'
'

1,2000
```

I am expecting the output something like this-

```
start, end
4436,4337

4336,4237

4236,4137

4136,4037
```

I writing a join statement. I am looking to check where I am wrong and what I need to correct.

```
SELECT (table2.no_id*100)-100+1 as start, table1.no_id as end,
table1.payments FROM earnings as table1, earnings as table2 
WHERE (table1.no_id= table2.no_id*100 AND table2.no_id>MOD(t2.max_no,100))

JOIN

(SELECT max(t2.no_id) as max_no FROM  earnings as t2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join on querying the `max(no_id)`, like you did, and check the difference between it and the row's `no_id`. Assuming the gap is `100`:

```
SELECT   no_id AS `start`, no_id - 100 + 1 AS `end`
FROM     my_table
JOIN     (SELECT MAX(no_id) AS max_no_id
          FROM   my_table)
         ON (max_no_id - no_id) % 100 = 0
ORDER BY no_id DESC
```

Comment: You're assuming there are no gaps in no_id.

Comment: @fancyPants - yup. The OP seems to have suggested that (4436 unique values with the max being 4436 and the min being 1).

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik. With a small change i.e no_id-100-1, this has work as i needed. Big help.

Comment: @NiteshOswal got my operators confused - thanks for noticing!